# AngularJS getElementById alternative

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using jquery CircularSlider Plugin. I am having 4 such sliders in one page. 
I have added custom values to the slider. Now I want to get value of each slider using angularjs Directive.

```
 var intensity = $('#intensity').CircularSlider({

      shape: "Half Circle",
      min : 0, 
      max: 2, 
      value:0,
      radius: 50,
      touch:true,
       setValue:function(value){
        console.log('inside set');
        value=value*10;
        return value;
       },
     formLabel : function(value, prefix, suffix){
        switch(value){
          case 0:
            return 'low';
          case 1:
            return 'med';
          case 2:
            return 'high';
        }
      }
      });
```

This slider shows low, high, medium values. 
I have written directive to get its value

```
.directive('exampleDirective2', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        console.log("angular way"+angular.element(elm[0]).text());
        console.log(elm[0]);                       
        console.log(attrs);        
    }
};
```

})

```
 <example-directive2>
   <div class="intSlider"  id="idInt1"> </div> </example-directive2>
```

But I have such 4 different sliders and want to wrap them in same directive and get its value depending upon id. Is it possible using same directive?
How can i get values for each id ?

Regards,
Shraddha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this once...

```
var yourElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#id' ) );
```